# How do I route an USB Audio Interface (MBox2) to a DAW (Qtractor) via Jack or Patchage as an audio channel?

Tags: sound, 15.10, jack, audio-recording

I'm borrowing an [Mbox2 Mini](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/digidesign-mbox-2-mini) and want to play around with this in Ubuntu 15.10 with gnome.

In with [jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qjackctl), I can see it as a MIDI device:

[image]

However, I can not see it as an audio input device:

[image]

**My Question:** Can my system see this as an *audio input channel* that can be routed via Jack or Patchage (into Qtractor)? What steps might I be missing? In QJackCtl I'm expecting to see the MBox as an audio channel. Am I on the wrong path?

[image]

My system sees the device as:

```
$ lsusb  | grep Mbox
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0dba:3000 Digidesign Mbox 2
```

And aplay:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: M2 [Mbox 2], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord output:

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: M2 [Mbox 2], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Extra information to try:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices

Comment: Looks like the driver should already be with the kernel, but Yeah go ahead and give it a try and tell us what happens

Comment: `aplay -l` lists only playback devices, what does `arecord -l` say about capture devices?

Comment: I've updated the question with `arecord -l`'s output. It seems to see it okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I was able to successfully use audio with qtractor. This is what I did with Qjackctl:[image: Qjackctl1]
[image: Qjackctl2]

And this is what I did inside of Qtractor. In the title bar you will see the word "track". Left click on this, then click on "Add Track". From here pick "audio", then click OK. [image: Qtractor3]

Now click on the R on the left hand side of the screen. [image: Qtractor4] After doing this, a circle should have turned red. This is the record button. [image: Qtractor5]

Click on that and then click on the play button just to the left of it. [image: Qtractor6]

Start talking into your microphone, it should be working. To stop it, press the play button again. I hope this helps.

Comment: A good lead. I'll try this back at home. Though I'm specifically looking to route the audio input (mic/line 1 and 2). Would this method work as well? An upvote for introducing me to a new tool!

Comment: Not sure to be honest but I will look into it on youtube. I usually use Audacity for audio. But I don't see why it wouldn't.